# Asignar una fuente (font) distinta a un div.?

Tags: php, html, css, fuentes

En mi web uso el siguiente codigo para cargar la font family en el archivo style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display|Poppins:300,400,500,600,700');
```

Cómo hago para asignarle esta font a un div en especial?

```
font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Arial, sans-serif;
```

Puse ese codigo en el style del div, pero no cambia nada. tengo que agregar algo mas?

Comment: Agrega tu HTML por favor

Comment: .job-post-item {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Arial, sans-serif;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #fff;}

Comment: las fuentes que cargas no incluyen la family Source Sans Pro, ej:https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200

Comment: Claro, deberia cargarla pero no se como...no se cual es el codigo ni donde va..

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar una fuente comun, como la Arial, Tahoma, etc.
Si estas haciendo tu codigo de forma local, puede ser que no tengas la fuente disponible.

Pero como te comenta BetaM, se necesita ver el HTML primero.

Comment: Solo intentaba ayudar al usuario, ya que no me permite comentar.